# rosbuild_find_ros_package() in catkin build

Tags: catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I recently try to port some of our old fuerte packages (which worked with rosbuild) to indigo (with catkin sysbuild). I already set up catkin build environment, now I must update the old macros of CMakeLists.txt to make it work with catkin following this guide:
http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/migrating_from_rosbuild

But there are some functions that are deprecated and do not have its equivalent, like this one:
rosbuild_find_ros_package({package_name})       DO NOT DO THIS

in rosbuild, this helps export the {package_name}_PACKAGE_PATH to make the search for files in package easier, but in catkin it dont exists.

There is something in catkin that I find similar, which is :
find_package()
But it results only in finding the packages that are already install (which can be found in **install** or **install_isolated** directory), if my package aren't build, it can't be found.

So are there any options to search, and export the path of unbuild packages (i.e package in **src** directory) under catkin sysbuild?

Thanks for any help,

Best regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/204553/rosbuild_find_ros_package()-in-catkin-build/) by [Huy Cong](https://answers.ros.org/users/21813/huy-cong/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2015-03-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No, with `catkin` you always have to build your packages before you can use / find them.

Have you tried building your package before and was there a problem in that case too?

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2015-03-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Huy Cong](https://answers.ros.org/users/21813/huy-cong/) on 2015-03-09**:
In fact, I want to browse a .cmake file which found under {package_name}, but I don't want to explicit the path (which is long & not portable), in catkin is there an easy way to search for a file under a source package that we already know the name?

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2015-03-09**:
After calling `find_package(foo)` you can use the variable `foo_DIR` which will point to the `cmake` folder of the package. You probably want to install other CMake files into that location.

**Comment by [Huy Cong](https://answers.ros.org/users/21813/huy-cong/) on 2015-03-10**:
But this means that I have to build that package before (since find_package didn't work with src package)? Is there any way to organize the order of build packages, because it seems that I have no control over it...

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2015-03-10**:
Yes, you must build a package before being able to use / find it. The order of the build is defined by the package dependencies. So if you want B to build after A because it needs to find A you should also define a dependency on B in As manifest.

**Comment by [Huy Cong](https://answers.ros.org/users/21813/huy-cong/) on 2015-03-11**:
Thank you, I'm reorganizing my packages thanks to packages.xml, now I'm able to move on